# Boxed text on Tikz path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

need texts on the first picture to be boxed(solid, not dashed), but lines to be dashed....
Here is MWE:

```
            \documentclass[10.5pt,b5paper]{memoir}
            \usepackage[english]{babel}
            \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
            \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
            \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
            \usepackage{xcolor} %
            \definecolor{gr}{RGB}{200,250,200}
            \usepackage{tikz}
            \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata}
             \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,
            decorations.shapes,shadows,backgrounds,decorations.markings}

            \begin{document}
            \begin{figure}[!h]
            \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            [auto,
            block/.style ={rectangle, draw=gr!10!black, thick, fill=gr,
            text width=7.1em,align=center, minimum height=4em, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}},
            line/.style ={draw, thick, densely dashed, -latex',shorten >=2pt},
            cloud/.style ={rectangle, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum height=7em, text width=7.1em, align=center}]
            \matrix [column sep=14mm,row sep=11mm]
            %draw,text width=100pt, text centered, line width=1pt, fill=gr, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2.5cm, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1.5pt}
            {
            &\node [block] (p1) {Programm 1}; &\\
            \node [cloud] (keyboard) {Keyboard}; &
            \node [block] (p2) {Programm 2}; &
            \node [cloud] (display) {Terminal}; &\\
            &\node [block] (p3) {Programm 3}; &\\
            };
            \begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
            \path (keyboard) |- node {\small{\hspace{2cm} test1 }} (p1);
            \path (p1) -- node[sloped,above] {\small{test1}} (p2);
            \path (p1)  edge [bend left=35] node[sloped,above,red] {\small{test 2}} (display);
            \path (p2) -- node[sloped,above,red] {\small{test1}} (display);
            \path (p3) -- node[sloped,above,red] {\small{test1}} (display);
            \path (p2) -- node[sloped,above] {\small{test1}} (p3);
            \path (p3) edge [bend left=-35] node[sloped,above] {\small{test 2}} (display);
            \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \end{center}
            \caption{I want texts on lines to be in box with solid line like below}
            \end{figure}



            \begin{tikzpicture}
            [auto,
            block/.style ={rectangle, draw=gr!10!black, thick, fill=gr,
            text width=7.1em,align=center, minimum height=4em, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}},
            line/.style ={draw, thick, densely dashed,  -latex',shorten >=2pt},
            cloud/.style ={rectangle, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum height=7em, text width=7.1em, align=center}]
            \matrix [column sep=34mm,row sep=11mm]
            {
            \node [block] (p) {Programm}; &
            \node [cloud] (display) {Terminal}; &\\
            };
            \begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
            \path decorate[decoration={markings, mark connection node=my node, mark=at position .5 with
            {\node [draw,red,transform shape] (my node) {How to make this box,but not line, solid?};} }] {(p) -- (display)};
            \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}

            \end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `draw,solid` option to the `node` command.

Comment: But with the first node (after 'Keyboard') sloped,above,draw,solid option gives very wide box

Comment: There is a way to well position the node, not in middle way, but more to end or more to beginning. Search for, please. I don't  remember.

Comment: `\path decorate[decoration={markings, mark connection node=my node, mark=at position .5 with
            {\node [draw,red,transform shape,solid,text width=2.5cm] (my node) {How to make this box,but not line, solid?};} }] {(p) -- (display)};`  @Sigur would you mind to writen an answer? (It's in the middle because of `pos = 0.5`.... but one does not have decorations for that at all, a simple `node[solid,draw,pos=...]` would do)

Comment: @marmot, please, feel free to post an answer, if you have time, of course. I'm quite busy now.

Comment: @Sigur There is no rush. That's your answer. I already wrote two just to make sure that there is an answer. ;-)

Comment: @marmot, done! Please, feel free to edit and improve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

[image]

Basically, the important part is:

`node[draw,solid,above=3pt,near end]` to insert the text node near end on the right angle arrow.

`node[draw,solid,above=3pt]` to draw the frame around the node in solid style and a little bit above, so the frame does not overwrite the arrow.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\definecolor{gr}{RGB}{200,250,200}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,
decorations.shapes,shadows,backgrounds,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    auto,
    block/.style={%
        rectangle,
        draw=gr!10!black,
        thick,
        fill=gr,
        text width=7.1em,
        align=center,
        minimum height=4em,
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}
    },
    line/.style={%
        draw,
        thick,
        densely dashed,
        -latex',
        shorten >=2pt
    },
    cloud/.style={%
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        fill=blue!20,
        minimum height=7em,
        text width=7.1em,
        align=center
    }
]
\matrix[column sep=14mm,row sep=11mm]
{
    &   \node [block] (p1) {Programm 1};            & \\
        \node [cloud] (keyboard) {Keyboard};    &
        \node [block] (p2) {Programm 2};            &
        \node [cloud] (display) {Terminal};     & \\
    &   \node [block] (p3) {Programm 3};            & \\
};
\begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
    \path (keyboard) |- node[draw,solid,above=3pt,near end] 
                {\small{test 1}} (p1);
    \path (p1) -- node[sloped,above=3pt,draw,solid]
                {\small{test 1}} (p2);
    \path (p1)  edge [bend left=35] node[sloped,above=3pt,red,draw,solid] 
                {\small{test 2}} (display);
    \path (p2) -- node[sloped,above=3pt,red,draw,solid] 
                {\small{test 1}} (display);
    \path (p3) -- node[sloped,above=3pt,red,draw,solid] 
                {\small{test 1}} (display);
    \path (p2) -- node[sloped,above=3pt,draw,solid] 
                {\small{test 1}} (p3);
    \path (p3) edge [bend left=-35] node[sloped,below=3pt,draw,solid] 
                {\small{test 2}} (display);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good. +1 ;-)